# Message Oriented Middleware with MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, msmq, message-queue

I'm reasking this, without being so long winded this time.  Has anyone used any message oriented middleware with MVC2?  Has anyone used MSMQ? Does anyone recommend anything?

Comment: I have used NServiceBus and love it.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, never heard of it but will check it out.